# How many hours of teaching do "12 taught US credits per academic year" correspond to?

Tags: united-states, teaching

It looks like that "12 taught US credits per academic year" is a common teaching load in research universities. However, I am not able to find the correspondence between "1 taught US credit" (actually 12, but I can just know for 1, and then multiply by 12) and the number of hours that a teacher needs to spend to cover that US credit. In other words, how many hours does a teacher need to work to teach 1 US credit. Also, approximately, how many hours are necessary, for a teacher, to prepare 1 US credit? Also, is this teaching workload common in european universities, or just in US universities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twelve credits *per term* in the US usually translates to approximately twelve (nominal) hours of student-facing group time (class time) per week over a term, which might be a semester or a quarter. Twelve credits *per year*, would be, in a semester system, six credits per term, so six "class hours" per week over the year.

There may be summer requirements or not, depending on the institution, though these are usually worked out and paid separately.

At many places Twelve Credit hours constitutes a "full load", especially at Liberal Arts Colleges. At research universities it would probably be much less: half of that or less.

An "hour" might be 50 clock minutes and there might be a different calculation for some activities such as labs rather than lectures. But a "credit hour" is approximately an hour per week for the term. If the term is 15 weeks then 1 credit hour is 15 "hours" facing students.

This doesn't account for preparation time or grading time, which is just assumed in the mix. It doesn't account for required office hours which are also typical.

A common deviation is something like a Four Credit Physics course with a lab. It could require three hours of class time and two or three of lab time, with the lab requiring more stand-up time than the lectures. In this case the "full time" definition might differ from that of, say, a history professor.

---

At research institutions the load might be defined in terms of courses, not credit hours. One place I'm familiar with the load of a professor was two courses per term, whether they were three credits or five from the student's viewpoint. At another it was one course per term though there were four terms per year. And a course might have anywhere from 20 to 300 students (or more, or less). With large classes, TA management may be part of the job as well.

---

In the US, don't expect that an academic position is only forty hours per week total. The teaching element won't (hopefully) require that much, but research and keeping current in the field normally takes us beyond any given limitation. It is easy to leave a production line behind at the end of a day, but harder to turn your brain off if you are an academic. On the other hand, some management jobs these days are 24/7 with all-hours expectations to respond to superiors. That is less likely in academia unless you specifically arrange for it. Some academics will respond to student email anytime and others won't.

Comment: Thanks a lot.... I read about the "12 taught US credits per academic year" in a research university..... but, if "12 taught US credits per academic year" correspond to around 12 hours of teaching per week, per term, this means around 3 to 5 courses per week, per term.... plus the time for preparing those lectures... Well, it looks like there is not time for research there.... right?

Comment: Ah, Per Year is different. That would be, on a semester system, six credits per term so six hours per week during each of the two terms. I'll make an edit.

Comment: This sounds right. I'd just point out briefly that 12hrs/year comes out to 2 classes fall, 2 classes spring in my mind. Depends on the institution, I'm sure, but 2-2 is indeed a reasonably standard research level load at least in math. Less and more both heard of.

Comment: At my R2 institution, 24 credit hours per year (12 per term) is the baseline faculty teaching assignment, and research faculty (at least in my department) get that reduced to 15 per year (6 or 9 per term) as long as they are active in their research.

Comment: @StevenClontz, some places (Duke, Stanford, others) have two kinds of faculty. Teaching faculty (Professors of the Practice) aren't tenured, perhaps, and have heavier teaching loads and long term contracts. They manage the undergraduate curriculum. Research faculty have lighter teaching loads focused on upper level undergrad and mostly grad courses. Lots of variability in academia.

Comment: Yup, I wasn't disagreeing with you, just providing a different perspective.

Comment: @StevenClontz, yep, and I was doing the same. Stay well.